# library using Quartz PDF rendering routines statically compiled and then ported to Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, quartz-graphics

is it possible to compile statically a c++ library under OSX which calls Quartz routines for PDF rendering and use it under Windows to be linked to a Windows c++ project?

Comment: No its not possible. If you have some flexibility in technology you can take a look at Qt/Poppler as a cross platform solution. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq27-poppler.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have added another compiler to OSX that targets Windows then possibly, otherwise no.

The standard compilers for OSX cannot compile for a Windows target.

Comment: isn't possible to compile just as a c++ pure library stuff?